# Calendar show more all-day events

Tags: calendar

Is it possible to increase the area dedicated to all-day events? It grows automatically up to 5 events, the 6th is partially shown and from the 7th they are hidden.

[image]

Comment: This appears to be set up in an Excel type template. Do you see why it shouldn’t be able to accommodate a ‘Fit To Size’ setting? This is what I would like to see.

Answer (score 1):

To see multiple (>5) "all day" events in a single day, you need to use the View by Day option.

Or alternatively you can use the week view but with scroll function.

[image: day]

Comment: I can scroll the events, what I would like to achieve is to always show them.

Comment: can you be specific, how many do you want to see, unlimited?, what about loosing the window space below?

Comment: 5 seems an arbitrary number. Unlimited would clearly be a problem, ideally the separator line should be moveable but since it is not possible a higher limit (e.g., 10) would be OK

Comment: see my updated answer